# Insert select with a twist question

Tags: mysql, insert

I Want to copy all the data of a table (with a certain id ofcourse) into the same table, but with a slightly difference.

I have this table (product_quantity):

```
id----groupId----productId----quantity

1 ----- 2 ------------2--------------5
```

What i want to do is to copy all the data that have groupId=2, insert it in the table with groupId=3

So I found that I could do a select-insert

```
insert into product_quantity (groupId, productId, quantity) SELECT groupId, productId, quantity FROM prouct_quantity WHERE groupId=2
```

But this will only make duplicates.

Is it possible to use this insert-select, but also insert a groupId=3, with just one query?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: RedFilter got you the answer. You might want to look up select into/replace into for future applications.  Should be no difference in result but the syntax is kind of fun :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this sql query:

```
insert into product_quantity (groupId, productId, quantity) 
select 3, productId, quantity from product_quantity where groupId = 2
```